# Handling voice over accessibility standard gestures

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I am trying to handle the touch to explore and one finger slide gestures when in the voice over mode, for my scroll view that has multiple buttons. I am implementing the UIAccessibilityFocus accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused protocol to update my scroll view offset.

However, I need to handle the single touch to explore gesture action differently to the the one finger slide gesture in voice over mode. I can't seem to find how to do this in the UIAccessibility documentation and would appreciate if someone can guide me or point me to the right solution. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

**No**, there is no practical way to accomplish this. Furthermore, you will want to reconsider the need. VoiceOver can be navigated using either tap or gesture and users expect both to behave  predictably and consistently across apps. In fact, some users may never tap, instead *always* navigating by swipe. You don't want confuse, or inadvertently lock out, users attempting to enjoy your app.